# Webpack DevServer HMR not working with ngrok->docker

Tags: webpack, quasar-framework, ngrok

I´m trying to get Webpacks DevServer HMR feature to work on my setup. It look like this:

- QuasarJS CLI runs Webpack DevServer for MYAPP in local Docker container
- Docker container is accessed through ngrok tunnel

docker ports

```
0.0.0.0:8201->8201/tcp
```

ngrok config:

```
Forwarding   https://MYAPP.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:8201
```

Webpack DevServer config (Webpack version: 5.59.1)

```js
devServer: {
  port: 8201,

  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  },

  client: {
    webSocketURL: {
      hostname: "0.0.0.0",
      pathname: "/ws",
      port: 8201,
    },
  },
},
```

In Chrome browser dev tools I can see that MYAPP is trying to connect to the local DevServer but does not succeed:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://MYAPP.ngrok.io:8201/ws' failed:

WebSocketClient @   WebSocketClient.js?8f51:13
initSocket  @   socket.js?d11d:15
eval    @   socket.js?d11d:34
```

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it in the documentation:

> To get protocol/hostname/port from browser use webSocketURL: 'auto://0.0.0.0:0/ws'.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#websocketurl

Now my Webpack DevServer config looks like this:

```js
devServer: {
  port: 8201,

  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  },

  client: {
    webSocketURL: "auto://0.0.0.0:0/ws",
  },
},
```

Works!

Comment: For react (where you don't have easy access to the webpack config), you can also use env vars like: WDS_SOCKET_PORT,  WDS_SOCKET_HOST and  WDS_SOCKET_PATH.